# Automatically create Gmail labels (and filters)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail

Is it possible to automatically create gmail labels (and filters) based on a subject of incoming mail?

Incoming subject should look like this: 123 word1 word2, so the labels hierarchy will be 123(root label)/word1/word2

It would be great if this script automatically filter incoming mail and put it to appropriate label.

Thanks

Comment: gmail and label hierarchy is a non sense. Please use an other mail system if you are willing to use nested labels! labels are not folders!

Answer (score 0):

Yes its doable with gas. You can search or create labels on the fly as you process the messages. You dont create filters, instead the code itself will label and move each email.
Not sure what the guy in your first question comment is ranting about. Gmail supports nested labels just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via google Apps script. Just create a trigger to run every minute for new message process.